# Azure Blob - ASP.NET, Copy Blob to within Same Collection

Tags: c#, azure, file, copy, blob

I am trying to copy from an existing Azure blob to a new location with the same file name. The two folders are in the same container. Any ideas?

```
                        // details of where we want to copy from
                        var sourceContainerName = blobContainer.ToString();
                        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(@dirItem.Uri.ToString());
                        var sourceFilePath = "192-168-2-44/img/" + fileName;

                        // details of where we want to copy to
                        var destContainerName = blobContainer.ToString();
                        var destFilePath = "192-168-2-44/archive/" + fileName;

                        var sourceContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(sourceContainerName);
                        var destContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(destContainerName);

                        Console.WriteLine(sourceContainer);
                        Console.WriteLine(destContainer);

                        CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob = sourceContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(sourceFilePath);
                        CloudBlockBlob destBlob = destContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(destFilePath);

                         await destBlob.StartCopyAsync(sourceBlob);
```

Comment: Are there any errors?  What are you seeing?

Comment: I am not seeing any errors in VS or Browser and files are not being transfered.

Comment: have you seen this?  https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip78.html  Just something I saw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test in my site and it works very well.

You could refer to the code as below:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("connectionstring");
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

var sourceContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("container");
var destContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("container");

var sourceFilePath = "hhh/www/" + "hello.txt";
var destFilePath = "hhh/jjj/" + "hello.txt";
CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob = sourceContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(sourceFilePath);
CloudBlockBlob destBlob = destContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(destFilePath);
await destBlob.StartCopyAsync(sourceBlob);
```